It - Preparatory subject
A preparatory subject is a placeholder noun used before the actual subject (infinitive expression, a clause) is introduced in the sentence.

It looks as if we're going to have trouble with Anna again. 

It felt like I was riding a normal bicycle not an electric bicycle.
I don't know if 'It' is a preparatory subject. Or should I use 'This bicycle' instead of 'It' if not preparatory?

It looked like it was going to rain, so we took an umbrella.


can we use 'It' as a preparatory subject in such sentences?
Or does 'It' before verbs like (sound, feel, look) only refer to some specific thing or situation?

These sentences are all fine.  Did you make them up yourself or take them from somewhere? Is there a reason you doubt it's OK to use "it" with "look", "feel"? "It looks like rain" is certainly very common. Here's a question on "it seems like..."

@StuartF 'It' is used as a preparatory subject or a pronoun that directly refers to something previously mentioned or the general situation like The music was too loud. It sounded horrible.

Yes, you can. All your examples are fine. The "it" is a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position.

Clearly the structure of the clause tells the listener to wait for the actual upcoming content that is the specific semantic subject of the utterance.

First, please say where this definition came from: while "preparatory subject" is a reasonable term, it is not one I have ever encountered before, (though I see that Wikipedia does have stub article on it).
By that definition, I don't think it is a preparatory subject in any of the sentences you quote, because the logical subject is not actually expressed - as is usual with expressions like "looks like" and "feels like".
The logical subject of the first one is something like "Our expectation of the experience we're going to have", and in the second one, something like "the experience I had of riding a bicycle".
Edit: as Stuart F says in a comment, the sentences are all fine; but no, you cannot use This bicycle as the subject without changing the meaning.
That would be a grammatical and meaningful sentence, but would not have quite the same meaning, because the sentence is about the experience, not about the bicycle.

@hwkal I disagree. In none of your examples is "it" a placeholder. It's a semantically empty pronoun doing nothing more then filling the obligatory subject position.

@BillJ 'It' is not preparatory here.

@hwkal That's what I said! Read my answer.


It looks as if we're going to have trouble with Anna again.
It felt like I was riding a normal bicycle not an electric bicycle.
It looked like it was going to rain, so we took an umbrella.

Yes, you can. All your examples are fine.
The "it" does not represent a semantic argument and cannot be replaced by any other noun phrase. There is no question of dummy "it" being a preparatory element, since the elements that follow it do not give the meaning if "it".
"It" is, then, just a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the obligatory subject position.

The phenomenon the term preparatory subject aka anticipatory subject applies to is where the pronoun It is a placeholder or "stand-in" for a subsequent declaration.
If I were king, I would not call such subjects either of those terms because such subjects require previous context, otherwise they are "out of the blue" non-sequiturs. Those terms are somewhat misleading.
Here is your clause that uses such a subject:

It felt like ...

Here is your declaration:

I was riding a normal bicycle not an electric bicycle.

What felt like that?  Riding the particular bicycle that has been the subject of your conversation up to that point felt like that.
Here is your sentence with an actual subject which is already under discussion (hence "that bicycle"):

{Riding that bicycle} felt like {I was riding a normal bicycle not an electric bicycle}.

Here is your sentence with an actual subject being introduced for the first time into your conversation:

Riding the Slipstream Model E felt like I was riding a normal bicycle not an electric bicycle.

You have to provide a meaningful subject when speaking of it for the first time in a conversation.
If you want to make the bicycle itself (not riding it) the subject of your sentence:

The Slipstream Model E felt like a normal bicycle not an electric bicycle.

It would be understood, with the word "felt", that you mean how it felt to ride the bicycle.

It feels good to ride a bicycle / Riding a bicycle feels good.
we often use 'It' as the preparatory subject as the placeholder for infinitive phrases. so according to you, 'It' here should also be replaced with something concrete as the subject.

@hwkal If you are making a very specific comment (e.g. comparing a particular e-bike's ride to a normal bike) it is practically expedient not to introduce the comparison to the conversation with "It felt like I was riding a normal bike not an electric bike".  It would be a non-sequitur, inasmuch as "It" has no antecedent but is anticipatory. But if you are making a very general statement or a pleasantry (e.g. "It feels good to be outdoors on a sunny day with a light breeze") then that practical consideration vanishes.

"It looks as if we're going to have trouble with Anna again." what about this?

The verb's tense in the "preparatory clause" plays a major role in whether the utterance is "out of the blue" or just a normal conversational segue.   Compare the difference between "It looked as if we were going to have trouble with Anna again" and "It looks as if we're going to have trouble with Anna again."
